# Nested Loops Java

Tags: loops, nested

I'm trying to do a homework problem that converts Polar Coordinates to Cartesian, and vice versa, using inheritance and polymorphism, that also gives the distance between points, slope of the line, and equation of the line given the two values entered by the user.

I created my parent class, and the Polar and Cartesian classes.  I'm trying to 1. call the methods in my test coordinates class (which it isn't recognizing for some reason), and 2. create a successful nested loop.

The loop situation: 
I have an if statement leading to either Polar coordinates entered or Cartesian coordinates entered.  This works well and once coordinates are entered, the user is prompted to select a process (get slope of line, equation of line, distance between the line, etc.).  I don't know how to create this nested loop.  Each time I try, it stops looping once I finish the inner loop, and won't go back to the outer loop to the menu.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Parent Code (I'm having trouble calling the methods):

```
public abstract class Coordinate {

    private double value1, value2;

    public Coordinate(double val1, double val2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public double getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }
    public double getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public abstract String getEquationOfLine(Coordinate c);

    public abstract double getDistance(Coordinate c);

    public abstract double getSlopeOfLine(Coordinate c);


}
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TestCoordinates {

    public static String getSelection(Scanner in) {

        System.out.println("(p) Polar Coordinates (r, theta (degrees))");
        System.out.println("(c) Cartesian Coordinates (x, y)");
        System.out.println("(x) Exit program");
        System.out.println("What type of coordinates?  Please enter p or c, or x to quit. ");
        return in.next();

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String coordinateString = getSelection(scan);

        while(coordinateString.equalsIgnoreCase("p") || coordinateString.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {


            if (coordinateString.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                System.out.println("Coordinate 1 - Please enter the radius: ");
                int radius = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Coordinate 1 - Please enter theta (degrees): ");
                int theta = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Coordinate 2 - Please enter the radius: ");
                int radius1 = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Coordinate 2 - Please enter theta (degrees): ");
                int theta1 = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.println("[1] Convert to Cartesian coordinates.");
                System.out.println("[2] Find the distance between the two points.");
                System.out.println("[3] Find the slope of the line between the points.");
                System.out.println("[4] Find the equation of the line between the points.");
                System.out.println("[5] Return to main menu.");

                System.out.println("What would you like to do? Enter the number: ");
                int num = scan.nextInt();





        /*if (num = 1) {
                    getCartesian();
                    System.out.println("The Cartesian coordinate for " + "(" + radius + "," + theta + ") is" + getCartesian);
                    System.out.println("The Cartesian coordinate for " + "(" + radius1 + "," + theta1 + ") is" + getCartesian);
                }*/

                /*if (int num = 2){
                    getDistance();
                    System.out.println("The distance between the Polar coordinates (" + radius + "," + theta + ") and " + radius1 +"," + theta1 + ") is" getDistance);
                }


                if (int num = 3) {
                    getSlopeOfLine;
                    System.out.println("The slope of the line between the Polar coordinates (" + radius + "," + theta + ") and " + radius1 +"," + theta1 + ") is" getSlopeOfLine);

                }

                if (int num = 4) {
                    System.out.println("The equation of the line between the points is: ")
                }

                else if (num = 5) {
                    return;
                }*/
```

Comment: You've got to show some code if you want help.

Comment: We need to see some code. Your nested loops need to use different variables.

Comment: If the problem is in your loop condition, the specifics of the homework problem probably aren't relevant. Provide a simplified example of how your menu/action loop code looks like, with as little of the ancillary details as necessary.

Comment: If we can see your inner and outer loop we might be able to see where you're going wrong

Comment: "isn't recognizing"...?

Comment: What errors are you getting? All I can see is an abstract class with no concrete instantiations?

Comment: coordinateString is your loop variable. Where is it changing within the loop?

Comment: When I do the multiple "if" loops with num=1, 2, etc, it says that it cannot convert from int to boolean.

Comment: It also says that for "getDistance" from the parent, "the method is undefined for the type testCoordinates."